# Using Jenkins to do CI/CD on EC2 Instance

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, wildfly, continuous-deployment

I don't know both Jenkins and CI/CD, so I want to get some advice here.

I have an EC2 instance, on that instance, it will have WildFly + Appeon, which I will deploy a War file on WildFly.

This War file will be stored in an S3 bucket. The Jenkins job will pick up the war file from S3, and then go to that EC2 instance, stop the WildFly server and Appeon, replace the WAR file on EC2 Instance, and restart Wildfly and Appeon.

What should I know to get this job done? Any advice?

Comment: you could just use a command line script that has aws cli commands and ssh commands inside of it. Jenkins can also run arbitrary commands. Just do a aws s3 cp ..... followed by scp, followed by ssh service X restart. I think you're safe copying the file then restarting the service

Answer (score 1):

I have similar job in my environment too. Im assuming this is a production environment (with two nodes) in an Load balanced architecture. For a graceful deployment, first before you stop the application, take the node out of the LB pool by removing the LB healthcheck to the node. Make sure the LB has connection draining enabled. The LB will then ensure all inflight users request to this node are completed before making the node as OutofService. The LB at this point will also start sending subsequent users request to the second node behind the LB  while you complete the deployment on node1.

That way the users will not see a white page or 504 server error